# What is the best way to sort a partially ordered list?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, topological-sort, partial-ordering

Probably best illustrated with a small example.
Given the relations

```
A < B < C
A < P < Q
```

Correct outputs would be

```
ABCPQ or APQBC or APBCQ ... etc.
```

In other words, any ordering is valid in which the given relationships hold.

I am most interested in the solution that is easiest to implement, but the best O(n) in speed and time is interesting as well.

Comment: Are you asking for a way to merge two sorted lists?

Comment: No, a single initially randomly ordered list

Comment: I still do not get the question, sorry. What do you mean by "randomly ordered"?
And if the result should be sorted, why do you have several possible results (which are, for me, not really sorted at all)?
Is another longer example possible?

Comment: @Kosi2801: A < B < C and A < P < Q are relationships, not lists. They specify that A must always come before B and B before C, but the relationship between B and P is not specified and therefore doesn't matter in the ordering.

Comment: I can't tell from the question what information you're starting with. Clearly you have a "<" operator that is defined for A and B, and for B and C, but does it work for A and C? In other words, do you have the transitive closure of "<"? If you do, then it seems to me you need a simple merge algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called [topological sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

The standard algorithm is to output a minimal element, then remove it and repeat until done.

Answer (score 1):

Do several sorts. First sort according to the first rule, then according to the second one and so on. Should work, unless your rules contain contradictions. sure easy enough to implement.

Comment: its just an example - there isn't just 2 rules in general

Comment: I am not sure that  the number of rules are an issue. The result will still be correct. a little performance issue maybe.

Comment: and it's important to be a stable sort

Answer (score 1):

You could repeatedly call make_heap, pop_heap in C++ with the sequence at hand.