# C# sorting using only less than relation

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

How does one sort an array of objects in C#, using only a less than relation. I.e. not using a tri-valued IComparer.

Using the IComparer interface and the Array.Sort[0] method is not a problem when the elements of the array constitute a total order[1]. In some cases we are however faced with the task of sorting partially ordered sets[2]. In these cases it is not possible to implement the IComparer interface correctly. There might be pairs of elements that are neither less than, equal to or larger than some other elements.

I could always implement my own sort algorithm, accepting a less than predicate, but there has to be some library function for this, or hasn't there?

[0] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: I don't think there's anything in the framework for this, no...

Comment: How do you order when there is no comparison between objects?

Comment: Oh ok. I looked at your link!

Comment: How would you sort `{}` and `{x,z}` ? If you know how you'd do it, you could do it with the `IComparer` interface as well.

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982592/topological-sorting-using-linq

Comment: You should note that partially ordered sets results in a graph, not an array or list.  You'll have to create the datastructure as well as the algorithm or find a 3rd party that has already done this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nick for finding the answer in another Stack Overflow post:

[Topological Sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982592/topological-sorting-using-linq)

In short; there is no easy library one-liner to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why you want to do this? It would make your sort slower. The reason for the -1/0/1 return of the usual sort is that you just need to check two elements once;
int[] myIntArray = new int[] { 10,40,20,35,8 }

when you compare [0] with [4], you get 1, and you then know that [4] is less than [0] and don't need to check [4] with [0] again.

but if you only use lessThan, you get "false" and dont really know if [4] is smaller than [0] without checking that specifically, because 10 < 8 is false, while 8 < 10 is true.

So, you see, I think you are not REALLY wanting to use only lessThan. Just use ICompare...

Also, for sorting and such, you are better off with a list than an array, i think. less boxing/unboxing.

Comment: Yes it will prevent a number of sort optimizations. Please refer to the link of partially ordered sets for information about why the IComparer won't work. Hint: it's an total equivalence relation and that's not available in po-sets.

Comment: I see... I guess you are better off with that other thread then :)