# NHibernate mapping-by-code in .NET 4.6 throws "Cannot extend unmapped class"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code, .net-4.6

I have project running for several months in same NH configuration that I opened today on a clean installation of Windows (VS 2015 RC is installed, also .NET 4.6 RC is installed, but project is targeting .NET 4.5)

In building of NH session factory when these lines are called:

```
var mapper = new AutoMapper();
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingFor(typeof(Entity).Assembly.GetTypes());
conf.AddMapping(mapping);
```

the last row throws an exception: `Could not compile the mapping document: mapping_by_code` with InnerException `Cannot extend unmapped class: [my_namespace].[my_entity_name]`. When I iterate through `mapping`, I can see there object with name `[my_entity_name]` and everything seems ok. Just this object is in collection after the objects that extends this object (I'm not sure if it can be a problem or the order doesn't matter).

On any other computer (other workstation, CI server, production and dev environment) we didn't notice this error, I suppose that it can be caused by installed .NET 4.6, this is the only machine with .NET 4.6. If I understand it correctly when .NET 4.6 is installed all projects targeting .NET 4.5 are running in .NET 4.6 runtime. I also tried to run it in VS 2013, but with no change... I was also checking .NET 4.6RC changelog but I didn't find anything that could cause this error. Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE:** I checked on .NET 4.5 machine the order of items in `mapping` collection and it is in correct order (dependent subclass is after the parent subclass), so it seems that the order of types returned by `GetTypes()` (no ordering is guaranteed) is coincidentally working in .NET 4.5, but not working in .NET 4.6 because `CompileMappingFor` does not reorder mappings of same type (here I have dependency SubClass -> SubClass).

Comment: I got the same problem with VS2015 (RTM) on Windows 10 (RTM). The application is still targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2, but as you write, "when .NET 4.6 is installed all projects targeting .NET 4.5 are running in .NET 4.6 runtime"

The exact error I received was `NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: mapping_by_code ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Cannot extend unmapped class`

NHibernate version: 4.0.3.4000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the reason was that the order of `Assembly.GetTypes()` is completely different in .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.6. It was a coincidence that order produced by .NET 4.5 was working... I modified it to following piece of code and it works.

```
var types = typeof (Entity).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => !t.IsInterface).PartialOrderBy(x => x, new EntityTypeComparer());
var mapping = mapper.CompileMappingFor(types);    

public class EntityTypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
{
    public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
    {           
        if (x == y)
            return 0;
        if (x.IsAssignableFrom(y) || (!x.IsAssignableTo<Entity>() && y.IsAssignableTo<Entity>()))
            return -1;
        if (y.IsAssignableFrom(x) || (!y.IsAssignableTo<Entity>() && x.IsAssignableTo<Entity>()))
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  `OrderBy` replaced with `PartialOrderBy`, you can find implementation here - [Topological Sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000160/2752500). This makes topological sort instead of regular sort - we have there objects that are not comparable (last return 0 in the comparer) and general OrderBy can produce wrong results.

Comment: Be very careful with the last `return 0` ... the comparison algorithm doesn't always compare the types that you think directly, but instead the comparison can be made through a 3rd type. Supose that you have types A, B, C and C inherits from B, in this case the comparer will do: A==B ... A==C ... then it assumes that B==C and you end up with the wrong order - the Compare method never gets called for types B and C!

Comment: Yes, you are right that this comparer is wrong. Actually it is not possible to use `OrderBy` and `IComparer` because the inheritance relation is just a partial order relation not a linear order relation. The right solution is to use the topological sorting. I'll rewrite it and update this question...

Comment: I updated the original code, just OrderBy was replaced with PartialOrderBy, the comparer was not modified. Thanks @gschuager for notice.

Comment: Here https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2931 and https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/453